selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.webelement
Есть данный сайт с криптовалютой: https://platform.arkhamintelligence.com/explorer/token/dogelon-mars
Необходимо собрать информацию о крупнейших держателей.
Моя проблема заключается в том, что я не могу получить доступ к html, чтобы забрать данные.
Первый раз попробовал получить данные с помощью request и beautifulsoup, не получилось. На selenium я работаю в первый, но благодаря документации м видео урокам, маленько понимаю как нужно работать. Но даже с помощью selenium у меня не получается забрать информацию, даже не могу забрать html код всей страницы.
Буду благодарен всем, кто поможет решить данную ситуацию, потому что хочу разобраться как работает парсинг таких или подобных сайтов

Вам надо добавить код, иначе вряд ли получите ответ.
